# How to write Lucene queries for website search engine

Tags: lucene, solr, search-engine

I plan to implement my website's search engine using Apache Solr.  I have a search index built, and one of its documents is:

Virtua Fighter 2

Performing a search of:
Virtua*

returns all records starting with "Virtua", as expected.

A search of "Virtua Fighter 2" returns an exact match.

I would like a search of "Virtua Fighter" to return Virtua Fighter 2 in its result set.  But a phrase search of Virtua Fighter omits Virtua Fighter 2 from its result sets.  And I'm unable to use a wildcard in a phrase search-- "Virtua Fighter*" does not return any results.

What type of query needs to be written to support this?  Or what types of Lucene queries are used for simple website search engines?

Comment: Consider a copy field that you use to do your searches against.  You would have to create a new field type and use the appropriate TokenizerFactories [http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#TokenizerFactories], but I'm not versed enough to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using a  Keyword analyzer for the titles? (Or another analyzer that doesn't split on tokens.)

You should just use a Standard Analyzer, then phrase queries will work fine.

Comment: That was it.  I was using a "string" field type for the titles, which must have been defaulting to a keyword analyzer.  I changed over to using a field type of "text" that Solr defines, which uses the proper analyzers.